# install Anaconda in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install Anaconda in Ubuntu 16.04, but it always reports some error. I have followed exactly the instructions in https://www.continuum.io/downloads#linux.

When I do conda update conda, I got the following errors

`$ /home/zhou/anaconda3/bin/conda update conda`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zhou/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/fetch.py", line 112, in fetch_repodata
    timeout=(3.05, 60))
  File "/home/zhou/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zhou/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/zhou/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zhou/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/home/zhou/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/home/zhou/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 184, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "/home/zhou/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 43, in SOCKSProxyManager
    raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
```

I have also tried to install anaconda in my mac, which works very well. Does any body know how to solve the above problem? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Did you read the docs? What are the SOCKS dependencies?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to anaconda so I have no idea what is SOCKS support in the error report.

Answer (score 0):

I had an alternative solution to the problem I had above. When I ssh from another computer to my office computer where the anaconda is installed, everything works well. I can install all the packages in anaconda from the other computer. Sounds crazy but I am now working in this way. Does anyone have an answer for this problem?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the proxy settings. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39959360/1509809) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15661226/1509809)